# localStorage value keeps changing after rerendering in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I am trying to make a dice game which stores the lowest number of dice rolls and shortest time taken to finish the game using a function that compares it other value of time and rolls and store the lowest in the local Storage
The value in the localStorage keeping changing back to 0 after re-rendering or refreshing

[Here’s the link to the code](https://github.com/Mkhaleddd/tenzies-game)

I don't seem to know  why the app is changing the value to its initial state and the value in local storage to 0

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. This site has some guidelines which unfortunately are not being followed in this post. Please take the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and check out the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for articles on as [how to ask a (good) question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Importantly the post is missing code that readers can use to reproduce the problem - please update the question with appropriate details.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please either mark an answer as correct or leave a comment stating what is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since rolls will always be lower than bestRolls at the start of the program bestRolls will be set to rolls because of the setRecords function.

```
function setRecords() {
    if (!bestRolls || rolls < bestRolls) {
        console.log(rolls);
        setBestRolls(rolls);
    }
    if (!bestTime || time / 10 < bestTime) {
        console.log(time);
        setBestTime(time);
    }
}
```

Which will always be called in one of your useEffects.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    let anyVal = die[2].value;
    let heldValues = die.every((die) => die.isHeld);
    let equalValues = die.every((die) =>
        die.value === anyVal ? true : false
    );
    if (heldValues && equalValues) setTenzies(true);
    setStart(false);
    setRecords();
}, [die]);
```

This is why your bestRolls resets every rerender. Also i'm not absolutely sure what your program is supposed to do so i can't say if this is intended, but even if you fix this and bestRolls don't reset, they will when you press the button, since rollDice sets rolls to its starting value (0) plus 1 and then sets bestRolls to that.

```
function rollDice() {
    if (!tenzies) {
        setDie((prevDie) =>
            prevDie.map((die) => {
                if (die.isHeld) return die;
                else return generateNewDice();
            })
        );
    } else {
        resetGame();
    }
    setRolls((prevRoll) => prevRoll + 1);
    setBestRolls(rolls + 1);
}
```

I think you should put more focus into structuring your code to make it more readable so that you can avoid errors like these. If this is not enough to solve your problem you can specify further and I will take an extra look.